# using JOptionPane to receive user's input

Tags: java, joptionpane

This is my original code that prompt the user to enter the file name. However, the user have to write inside the console in order to work.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
        String filename = bf.readLine();
        File file = new File(filename);
        if (!filename.endsWith(".txt")) {
            System.out.println("Usage: This is not a text file!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Now i wanted to create a JOptionPane to prompt the user to type inside the pane. 
This is my code.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Object result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter a blog website");
        String word2 = (String) result;
        word2 = bf.readLine();
        File file = new File(word2);
        if (!word2.endsWith(".txt")) {
            System.out.println("Usage: This is not a text file!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

There are some further coding that receive the user's input and process them. However, after creating the joptionpane, nothing happens. The joptionpane came out, but after type in the input, nothing happens. Mind point where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the value after you read it.

```
    Object result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a blog website");
    String word2 = (String) result;

    File file = new File(word2);
    if (!word2.endsWith(".txt")) {
        System.out.println("Usage: This is not a text file!");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

If you are using a JOptionPane then you do not need the BufferedReader.